# Which one is correct: "after a century of" or "after a century from"?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

I have two sentences:

> 1. The Solvay conference, after a century of the first one, brought all the physics geniuses together once again.
> 2. The Solvay conference, after a century from the first one, brought all the physics geniuses together once again.

Which one would be the correct one (preposition *of* or *from*)? Or do I need to write something else?

Comment: Neither. Use *a century after the first one* as the parenthetical phrase.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Beg, why?

Comment: The prep. *of* is natural with *after* -- think of it, *after* doesn't go with *from*. IOW, you don't need *after* in case of using *from*: "The Solvay conference, a century from the first one, brought all the physics geniuses together once again." HTH.

Comment: @AndrewLeach,@Kris Thanks a lot.  So here `century` works like an adverb (Cf. `tomorrow`). I was treating it as a noun. Does *... a century later the first one ..* work? Or what about *.. after a century passed the first one ...* ?

Comment: _century of_ means that something was continuously happening for a century, e.g. _after a century of war, they finally surrendered_.

Comment: @Kris - I think you would like this phrase: "Pray tell," or "May I ask, ...?".  (*Beg* doesn't work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearer: "The recent Solvay Conference, held a century after the first, once again brought together all the physics geniuses."

You might want to say "the world's physics geniuses."